# Is there a way to test a double value like near in gtest

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I'm unable to find a proper way to test a `double` value in the unit test library test from google.

```
test("circle > constructor", () {
            var s = circle(vector(0, 0, 0),
                           4);
            expect(s.origin, vector(0, 0, 0));
            expect(s.area, ...);
            expect(s.circumference, ...);
        });
```

Is there a function like `near(value, accuracy)` function from gtest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [closeTo](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/closeTo.html):

```
expect(s.area, closeTo(value, accuracy));
```